# Hibernate não Alterar Automaticamente no Banco de Dados

Tags: java

gostaria que e o Hibernate não fizesse alterações diretamente no banco de dados, ou seja, gostaria que ele seguisse o que está no banco de dados.
Exemplo : Caso na minha entidade eu tenha a seguinte situação

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="locacao_codcliente", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "LO_CL_FK"))
private Cliente cliente;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="locacao_codvendedor", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "LO_VE_FK"))
private Vendedor vendedor;
```

Notem que eu teria dois campos que são chave estrangeiras que irão receber os nomes locacao_codvendedor e locacao_codcliente.

Gostaria que caso o DBA não tivesse criado estes campos lá no banco de dados ele não criasse automaticamente. Estou começando agora e prefiro seguir o padrão de que os campos já estejam criados no banco de dados.

A criação do meu banco de dados está conforme abaixo :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sitiusdb?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu ddl-auto  está configurado para update, ou seja, o hibernate vai comparar o que esta no seu banco com os modelos e gerar as alterações cfme os modelos. Para desativar isso tem que trocar o valor de update para none. Arquivo completo abaixo.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sitiusdb?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Os outros valores possíveis são:

- validate: validar o schema mas não faz mudanças no banco.
- update: faz update do schema.
- create: cria o schema, apaga dos dados anteriores.
- create-drop: drop o schema quando  o SessionFactory é fechado, ou seja quando para a aplicação apaga

Comment: Realmente deu certo. Ele não cria nem a tabela. Acho mais confortável trabalhar assim do que deixar o hibernate dominar o banco de dados. Acho muito arriscado e já fiz algumas coisas erradas uma vez.

Comment: Também prefiro não deixar o hibernate mexer na estrutura do banco, mas para não ficar gerenciando o banco na mão uso o liquibase, quando tiver um tempo de uma olhada é uma excelente ferramenta para gerenciar mudanças no banco.

Comment: Bom dia, crie uma outra pergunta com este questionamento, fica mais fácil de te ajudar e mais organizado